# Why did pressure decrease above the piston?

Tags: pressure, hydraulics

I can understand the pressure increase below,but why did pressure decrease above as more bricks were added?

Image source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4REdJIW6-Kg

[image: Piston pressure 2]

[image: Piston pressure 1]

Answer (score 1):

Because as the piston was moved down by the mass of the bricks the volume above the piston was increased.

With the valve closed then the fluid expanded to still fill that increased volume and the pressure decreases.

Comment: Isn't oil incompressible, though?

Comment: oil is  considered "nearly" incompressible in most applications.  Small changes in volume can increase/decrease pressures dramatically in a closed system.

Comment: "*Isn't oil incompressible, though?*" It might be incompressible but it *is* pressurisable (if that's a word). Think of water pressure increasing with depth in the ocean. It's not compressed but it is under increasing pressure with depth.

Comment: @OsvaldoSilva check out https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/bulk-modulus-elasticity-d_585.html then think about what might happen to a fluid subjected to reduced pressure... gas coming out of solution?